# for loop backwards with if statement

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I basically want to do something if whatever is true and if whatever is false I want to do the same thing but backwards. I tried it this way and it works but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. It would be nice to only write doSomething once. I also calculated 5000.799465 "by hand" which also doesn't seem very nice. I appreciate any help, I'm using java.

```
if (whatever) {
    for (double j = 0.0001; j < 5001; j = j * 1.1) {
        doSomething(j);
    }
} else {
    for (double j = 5000.799465; j > 0.0001; j = j / 1.1) {
        doSomething(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (....) {.... {`  that pseudo-code is nails on a chalkboard for me. But seriously, what is wrong with using an if statement? If the code is clean and easy to understand, stick with it.

Comment: And yeah, avoid "magic" numbers. Simply put your calculated value in where needed.

Comment: I had to fix that pseudocode as it was driving me nuts

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels at least it's a short drive. ;)

Comment: Does something depend on the value of `j`? If so, how? If not, why does it matter?

Comment: Seeing as your loops don't do anything with the value of j, they are both identical. Both call doSomething 187 times. That being the case: `for (int j = 0; j < 187; j++) doSomething()`

Comment: Haha, sorry about the pseudocode :D. Well it just doesn't seem very efficient to me to write "doSomething" twice. I thought I could write "for" and "doSomething" once and put the "if" inside "for" but that didn't work.

Comment: My loops do something with the j, it's a very long code and I didn't feel like writing everything

Comment: You don't have to "write everything", you can just give a better example, like I just did with my edit.

Comment: Ok thanks, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like whatever you are trying to do requires 187 iterations, so lets start there.

```
double j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 187; i++){
    if (whatever) {
        j = .0001 * Math.pow(1.1, i);
    } 
    else {
        j = .0001 * Math.pow(1.1, 186 - i);
    }
    doSomething(j);
}
```

The logic behind this is that you are going in opposite order if `whatever` is false by subtracting `i` from the exponent.

Now you can use j with your `doSomething()` but you won't have to use wacky numbers for your loop, and you can easily change it if you must rework the code.

Comment: My calculation was by doing log(base1.1)(5001 * .0001) which was 186.0004. I may have excluded/included incorrectly however. Either way though, you could just change my 186/185 to the proper numbers and the logic should still apply.

Comment: @Michael alright, then I must've excluded one of the ends I should've included in my calculation. I'll update the post.

Comment: You don't even need the j variable.  Use the ? operator...
```doSomething(.0001 * Math.pow(1.1, whatever ? i : (186 - i)));```

Comment: I edited your answer as you had compilation issues.